# We found a pre-release version of Office error

Tags: ms-office

I just wiped my machine and did a fresh install of Windows 8 and updated it to Windows 8.1.

I am trying to install Office Professional 2013 and I am getting this error:

> We found a pre-release or Beta version of an Office product on your
>   computer and can't install because of it.  Please uninstall any
>   pre-release Office software using the Programs and features item in
>   the Control Panel and try installing again.

The thing is, this is the first time I've tried to install office since wiping the hard-drive and re-installing Windows.  So there is no Pre-release or Beta version installed.  The only software I have installed since the machine was wiped, is Windows, Visual Studio 2012 and Kaspersky Internet security.

I downloaded the Microsoft Fix It tool and it is also throwing an error when I attempt to run it saying

> The program encountered an error trying to contact the server

Has anyone encountered this or know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

So I got this sorted in the end.

1. I downloaded the Office FixIt tool which Uninstalled office.  I think what happened was the first attempt to install Office failed for some reason, so when I went to re-run it, it thought I had a version already installed.
2. I deleted the temporary internet files through the Settings, Options, menu in Internet Explorer.
3. I downloaded the Office click to run.exe again but saved it as a different filename.  I just called it office.exe.
4. Ran the office.exe file I downloaded in Step 3 and it worked, although the installation was very slow.

For some reason my download speeds from Microsoft today seem very slow, not sure if that had something to do with it.

Anyway Office is installed now.